# Estimated Row Size for InnoDb query - buffer size greater than configured maximum

Tags: mysql, ssis, size, innodb

What would an estimated row size in bytes be for a query that returns the following:

```
CHAR(255) x 10 columns
TIMESTAMP x 1 column
INT(11) x 2 columns
```

Does the actual content determine the size or is it the above info.  If the actual content how can I calculate a good estimate?

Reading around I estimate 2562 based on (using latin1 charset):

```
 2 x INT(11)    = ( 2 x 4    )     8
 1 x TIMESTAMP  = ( 1 x 4    )     4
10 x CHAR(255)  = ( 10 x 255 )   2550
                                -----
                                 2562
```

Is that right?

I'm setting the properties of an SSIS package ADO .NET source to:

```
DefaultBufferMaxRows:    10000
DefaultBufferSize:       25620000
```

The problem is the DefaultBufferSize was higher than this before and I was getting errors:

> > Rows in buffer type 0 would cause a buffer size greater than the configured maximum. There will be only 1835 rows in buffers of this type.

Comment: Read about MySQL's [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/storage-requirements.html).

Comment: Why 255*255 and not 10*255?

Comment: Hmm... good point - I've corrected my question!

Comment: "*DefaultBufferSize was higher than this before*"?  Do you mean *lower*?

Comment: No I mean higher - that's what I don't understand!

Comment: Are the `CHAR` columns always going to have 255 characters of data?  If not, they should probably be `VARCHAR`s.